# Azure Redis Cache Authorization Header

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am working on the `Azure Redis` Cache, and I am using a `REST API` to create a cache. The response I get is :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
    "message": "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."
  }
}
```

I could not find any `Authorization header` in the documentation. Can someone suggest the procedure to generate the authorization header ?

Comment: Hey @Cylian. Can you help me with the authorization header part ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to create a Redis Cache account using this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/redis/Redis/Create?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes i am using the same link. I am trying to make API Calls to set up the cache. But it asks for the Authorization header. i dont know how to generate it ?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially creating an `Azure Redis Cache` account operation is an `Azure Resource Manager (ARM)` operation. Each ARM operation requires an `authorization` header that must be included in the request. Because you didn't include this header in your request, you're getting this error.

Please see [`Resource Manager REST APIs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-rest-api) for detailed instructions on how you can authenticate your ARM API requests.